# ValueError: time data '2022-07-25 15:35:50.717 +0530' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d,%H%M%S%f%z'

Tags: python, datetime-format

I need to print a specific date along with time in the format yyyy/mm/dd HH/MM/SS when the input is given in the format yyyy/mm/dd HH/MM/SS/%f/%z

I tried this code:

```
import datetime

print(datetime.datetime.strptime("2022-07-25 15:35:50.717 +0530", "%Y-%m-%d %H%M%S%f%z").strftime("%m/%d/%Y %H%M%S"))
```

and was expecting an output in the format 2022/07/25 15:35:50 but got an error:

```
ValueError: time data '2022-07-25 15:35:50.717 +0530' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f%z'
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot about `:` in between hour, minute, second.

```
import datetime

print(datetime.datetime.strptime("2022-07-25 15:35:50.717 +0530", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f %z").strftime("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S"))
>>> 07/25/2022 15:35:50
```